# EventLog WriteEvent - how do I suppress the text "For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp."

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

When writing my own events to the error log, do I have to have the following text inserted on every message? Is that provided by the error reader of the Microsoft Event Viewer or is that inserted with every message?

```
For more information, see Help and Support Center at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

How can I suppress it?

Yes, I'm pretty much worried about the wrong thing here. I was just curious and figured this would be an idle curiosity question to let the SO crowd mull over.

Comment: Where are you seeing that message?  We do that with the event log and I don't see that text in any of our messages in Event Viewer.

Comment: @Kirk Woll ~ In the event viewer on Windows ...

I guess it's tacked on by default by Windows

Comment: Strange, I don't see that message in Event Viewer for any sort of message (our custom ones or system ones).  FWIW, on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something Microsoft inserts on viewing, not something that is attached to my message. This is a non-question.

Comment: If you hadn't answered your question, I think that you could have deleted it.

Comment: I wanted to leave it in case others asked the same question. If I can /facepalm, others will too... And I could still delete it now.